# Strange web server issue

Tags: windows, apache, webserver, wamp, easyphp

Recently I uninstalled IIS and switched into [Easy PHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) (WAMP based). After install when I try to open administration got this screen.

[image]

I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security so I thought, maybe it blocks some ports or file activity. I added whole Easyphp folder, Apache, Easy Php executive file into trusted apps list

[image]
[image]

No success! Same screen appears again.

Then I tried to turn off Kaspersky. Here is result:

[image]

EasyPHP doesn't show any problem; it indicates that all goes well

[image]

Here is Apache log:

```
[Sun Oct 28 04:05:41.216924 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 596] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 28 04:05:41.217924 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 596] AH00456: Server built: Apr 20 2012 19:24:55
[Sun Oct 28 04:05:41.217924 2012] [core:notice] [pid 5736:tid 596] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\EASYPH~1.1\\Apache\\bin\\apache.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-12.1/apache'
[Sun Oct 28 04:05:41.308985 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 596] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9188
[Sun Oct 28 04:05:46.196728 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9188:tid 664] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Also checked if there is application that listens port 8080 with `netstat -a` command. There is no application listening port 8080.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the troubleshooting of the issue will consist of several common steps:

- You've tried only `127.0.0.1:8080` so far. Have you tried `localhost:8080`? It's worth trying since it *could* work and such behavior will indicate a network settings issue.
- Do you have any events logged except the ones you've mentioned? If no Access / Operational or Error events got logged this could indicate that the request doesn't even reach the server, and again you should check the network configuration.